# Return hasManies of hasMany - LSAdapter

Tags: ember.js

Im not sure how to do more complicated queries in Ember. For example, if a company has many tags, and tags have many requests, how would I get all the requests of all the tags that a company subscribed to? Something along these lines does not work...

```
var requests = company.get('tags').then(function(tags){
                tags.forEach(function(tag){             
                    return tag.get('requests');
                });
            });
```

Here I can console.log each tag, but how do I get the route to return all the requests? What I can do is load these requests and return store.all('request') but thats not really ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new array and populate it manually.

if you're using a model hook it would be something like this:

```
return company.get('tags').then(function(tags){
  var ret = [];
  tags.forEach(function(tag){             
     ret.pushObjects(tag.get('requests'));
  });
  return ret;
});
```

If requests are async and you want the records instead of the promises you'd want to grab all of the promises and wait on them, then add the results of those to the collection.